# How to Change the Name of style in xaml when Button is pressed in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have two styles name like MyStyleButton and MyStyleClick, If button is pressed then I want to apply MyStyleClick style else another MyStyleButton in Xaml.

```
<Button Name="btnExportPDF" Content="PDF" Click="btnExportPDF_Click" Height="40" Width="100" Style="{StaticResource MyStyleButton}" Margin="5" />
```

Comment: <Button Name="btnExportPDF" Content="PDF" Click="btnExportPDF_Click" Height="40" Width="100" Style="{StaticResource MyStyleButton}" Margin="5" />

Comment: Wondering if styling a ToggleButton with a control template is what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18201435/880709

```
private void AnotherWay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["AnotherWayStyle"];
}
```

Comment: I would like to do only in Xaml page but not dynamically

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b25973bb-9e9c-4a99-8234-39a042e0a478/apply-styles-dynamically-to-buttons-in-xaml?forum=wpf

Answer (score -1):

An example is with jQuery but it has more then 1 way to do this

```
jQuery.(".theClass").attr("class","Name of new class");
```

Comment: I want in Xaml WPF not Jquery

Comment: @Bhavanaky look at the answer from Anatoly Ruchka it's also a way in wich he linked in

Comment: @Bhavanaky that's also a way  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783005/how-can-i-change-styles-of-xaml-file-using-data-binding

Comment: Hi Hugo,I would like to add in Xaml page but not in .cs file, Is there any way to do like that

Comment: @Bhavanaky you don't have to make this in cs file you can simply makte this in u're xaml page :)